# Laravel 5 - Understanding why conditional statement required

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following Model structure

```
User
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | userName     |      ...
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+

UserActivity
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | activityName |   userId
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+

UserActivityType
+----+--------------+--------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | label        |   userActivityId
+----+--------------+--------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

A User can have One UserActivity.

A UserActivity can have one to many UserActivityType

Now I have a page which seperates the displaying of content by tabs.  Therefore whenever this page is loaded,
all of the tab content is also loaded.  Due to this, I need to handle the situation whereby I check that what 
I am trying to load exists, otherwise I will get a Trying to get a property of a ... error.

There is something I am trying to understand.  On one of the pages, I am doing something like this

```
@if (count($user->userActivity) !== 0)
    @if (count($($user->userActivity->userActivityType) !== 0)
        @foreach($user->userActivity->userActivityType as $label => $value)

        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
```

Now the above works without problems.  However, because I am trying to get information from userActivityType, do
I really need to check $user->userActivity first?  Instead of doing the above, I would think it would make more sense
just doing

```
@if (count($($user->userActivity->userActivityType) !== 0)
    @foreach($user->userActivity->userActivityType as $label => $value)

    @endforeach
@endif
```

However, doing this then throws the error mentioned above.  Why would it throw an error just for this?  I am still checking
if it exists, but it does not seem to pay attention in this situation?

Any explanation appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the error continue like "..property of non object"? If that is the case, that happens because you do not null check.

It would be better if you write it like that

```
if(! is_null($user->userActivity))...
```

Because it seems that one of the return types of the $user->userActivity is "null". And when you try to get property of null; php raises the exception.

```
$user->userActivity = null;
(null)->userActivityType; // ??? Exception thrown.
```

However when you say

```
if(count(null) != 0)
```

The code works because

```
 count(null) = 0 in php.
```

And the interpreter only continues if the object is set.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was something to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `$user->userActivity->userActivityType`, well, the `userActivityType` is a child object of `userActivity` so if there is no `userActivity` then when you'll use `$user->userActivity->userActivityType`, you'll get an error because unless a `$user->userActivity` is available, you can;t just use `userActivityType`. So you need to check if a `$user->userActivity` is avalable then you may check if there is also `userActivityType` available under `$user->userActivity`. So you may do it using something like:

```
@if($ua = $user->userActivity && $ua->userActivityType)

@endif
```